# ReadAsStringAsync return empty string

Tags: c#

I wrote a class that download the `html` structure of a web site. This works well, but some times (I can't really figure out of why) the method `ReadAsStringAsync()` return an empty string, and this cause me a lot of problems, because the returned "html" have no text inside, and then the method that use `HtmlAgilityPack` fails to analyze it. This is my class:

```
public class NetworkHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Configure the client to handle web request.
    /// </summary>
    static Lazy<HttpClient> httpClient = new Lazy<HttpClient>(() =>
    {
        var handler = CreateHandler();
        return new HttpClient(handler)
        {
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)
        };
    });

    /// <summary>
    /// Web request handler.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Return an object HttpMessageHandler.</returns>
    static HttpMessageHandler CreateHandler()
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();

        //If the framework support it, se a specific redirect.
        if (handler.SupportsRedirectConfiguration)
        {
            handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            handler.MaxAutomaticRedirections = 5;
        }

        //Set page compression.
        if (handler.SupportsAutomaticDecompression)
        {
            handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        }

        return handler;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the html from a web page.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">Url of the site.</param>
    /// <returns>Return a string that contains the html.</returns>
    public async Task<string> GetHtmlAsync(Uri url, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        //This protocol is used to exchange the information from client to server.
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        //Get web page html.
        var response = await httpClient.Value.GetAsync(url, cancellationToken);
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return content;
    }
}
```

The class also handle the redirects, but I want focalize the attention on `GetHtmlAsync`, this method works well, but usually return an `empty` string. I thought that could be the server that is busy or something like that, in this case how can I manage this situation?

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: is httpstatuscode succeeded?

Comment: If the *server* sends no HTML, `ReasAsStringAsync` won't return anything. BTW the `CreateHandler` method is somewhat pointless. You create a default `HttpClientHandler` instance so `SupportsRedirectConfiguration` and `SupportsAutomaticDecompression` will have their default values

Comment: @Charanoglu are you *sure* the server returned anything? Opening the URL in a browser doesn't mean you'll get the same result as an HTTP call, eg if authentication or redirection is involved. Use Fiddler or a similar debugging proxy to see what's actually returned from the server. And remove the `Supports` calls.

Comment: @Charanoglu if the response is succeeded then there should be content however you have to check what is status code because the site might return 201 which is succeeded but no cotent. To sum check the status code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos okay, it's happened now again, I wrote after `response` this: `var code = (int)response.StatusCode;` and the code is 503, of course `content` variable is empty.

Comment: 503 is not succees status code :)

Comment: @miechooy the app run always online on a server, what do you suggest in this case?

Comment: @Charanoglu 503 is a *server failure* code. The server failed. The response contains bot the status code and reason

Comment: @Charanoglu there is nothing you can do - there is server error

Comment: @Charanoglu contact the administrator of the application and ask him to check the logs. The *server* failed, not the HttpClient call. On the other hand, it could be that your call was missing eg a cookie or header that caused the server to crash, although it *shouldn't* have. It should have returned a 400 error - Bad request

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos when I check `ReasonPhrase` I get: `Service Unavailable`

Comment: That means the server crashed. Contact the server's administrator. BTW you don't need `Lazy`, HttpClient is thread-safe. It's not expensive to create either

Comment: lazy? what do you mean?

Comment: You don't need `static Lazy<HttpClient> httpClient`. HttpClient is thread-safe and there's no need to *delay* its construction.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in my environment I need to set a specific timeout, that's why I used it

Comment: @Charanoglu timeouts are configured on HttpClient, HttpHandler or the call itself. You've already configured that with the `Timeout` property. Lazy is only used for thread-safe lazy initialization. You could have used a static constructor to initialize the client in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the server is busy and doesn't send any request, for the moment I fix this using this code:

```
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    content = await new NetworkHelper().GetHtmlAsync(url);
else
    content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
return content;
```

essentially if the status code is unsucessful, then the method is execute again, this working for me, maybe someone could suggest another solution